# how to edit rdlc report without using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, report, rdlc

I am now working on `Sql Server Management Studio` and Visual Studio C#. I created an `Stored Procedure` to retrieve data from tables in database. Using the result `dataset` , I created a `rdlc` report using visual studio report designer.

I will install this software(software i am developing) in different systems in different locations. The problem is, the users may want to change the design(only the design, not `dataset`) of the reports and I can't install visual studio on all those systems. So, I would like to know is there any tool that can be used to change only the design of the `rldc` report, which is less in size, easy to install (comparing to visual studio)

Comment: So, you cannot install visual studio, but what about other software? Maybe [the report builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017#download) will do

Comment: I tried report builder, but I can't open rdlc file, it only support rdl file? Is there any way to open rdlc file in report builder ? @PeterBons

Comment: "I can't install visual studio on all those systems" - Remember that it will install VS Community Edition, which is free.