# RDLC files in Reportbuilder?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0

I have a question. I am working on a .Net project that consist of bunch or RDLC report files. I am finding uncomfortable with the Visual studio reporting services to edit the RDLC files.
Is it possible to use/edit an RDLC file in Microsoft report builder tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Report Builder cannot open .rdlc files it supports .rdl files. You can simply convert .rdlc files to .rdl manually:

- [Converting RDLC Files to RDL Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms252109(v=vs.120))

> A report with extension ".rdl" is a server report, and the a report with extension ".rdlc" is a local report. A server report need to be published to a Report Server, and the local report is used for the ReportViewer control that is running in local mode.

**References and Similar questions**

- [How to develop client side SSRS report using Reports Builder 3.0 and embed in ReportViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426048/how-to-develop-client-side-ssrs-report-using-reports-builder-3-0-and-embed-in-re)
- [how to edit rdlc report without using visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166941/how-to-edit-rdlc-report-without-using-visual-studio) *(read the comments)*
- [a way to save](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fde70ae1-2657-4809-979e-d9b4afdd3e46/a-way-to-save?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this